# Can I make lambdas deduce the variant return type?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, std-variant

This mostly theoretical since I can always spell out the return type, but I wonder if there is a way for me to tell lambda that return type should be union(std::variant) of all returns in lambda body.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct A{
    int val = 47;
};

struct B {
    float val = 4.7;
};

int main()
{
    for (int i=0;i<8;++i){
                      // can this be something like -> auto_variant  (auto_variant is some library type)
        auto var = []()->std::variant<A, B> {
            if (rand()%2 ){
                return A{};
            } else {
                return B{};
            }
        }();
        std::visit ([](const auto& val) {std::cout<< val.val << std::endl;}, var);
    }
}
```

note: my strong feeling is that the answer is NO, this is not possible, but I am curious if somebody knows some trick.

note2: using std::any does not fit my requirements, since I want the return type of lambda be known at compile time, instead of at runtime(with `any_cast`).

Comment: I'm 99.99999% sure this can't be done.  You'd need to inspect every return path, and I don't even think reflection could help you there.

Comment: *"my strong feeling is that the answer is NO"* Same here. I don't see how we can deduce a `std::variant<A, B>`. Maybe with reflection (But I doubt also we can do that).

Comment: If it was possible, why would it deduce to `std::variant<A, B>` and not `std::variant<B, A>`?

Comment: IMPO this is example of overusing lambda. When I'm coding I'm avoiding complex lambdas as much as possible. Complex code I extract to function/method which then lambda uses. With this approach your problem will not exists, since you will have a function which returns `std::variant` so deduction of return value of lambda is not a problem. Note this is my personal practice which I'm finding quite useful, so if you do not like it do not complain on it.

Answer (score 3):

You will find I'm cheating but maybe

```
using A_or_B = std::variant<A, B>;
```

then

```
[]() {
  if (rand()%2) {
    return A_or_B{A{}};
  } else {
    return A_or_B{B{}};
  }
}
```

does the trick?

Comment: First, this really doesn't automate this, which I beleive is what the OP is looking for.  Also, why not use a trailing return type so you don't have to keep repeating `A_or_B`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree with you (thus my first words...), but I don't know the OP's intention, so why not? (and some complain about posting short answers as comments, that's why I dared posting this answer I find a bit ridiculous...)